# Expression Regular - Back References

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this information:

- target = 16-10-2017
- pattern = `/([0123][0-9])-(\1)-(\d{4})/g`

My question. Why the 'back reference' doesn't work? I'd like to understand what the syntax does and where i did make the mistake. Because in my understanding the first group `([0123][0-9])` should consider both numbers '10' and '16', or not? why?

[Regex Example Online](https://regex101.com/r/GZxpAx/1/)

Comment: A back-reference works like a copy / paste of *the string* matched before not *pattern* itself.

Comment: What is `(\1)` intended to do? Shouldn't it be `(\d{2})`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **backreference** only matches the same text that was captured with the corresponding **capturing group**. It does not repeat the pattern, but the already captured value.

In your case, `\1` tries to match `16` after the first `-`.

In JS regex, you can't use `(?1)` / `\g<1>` subroutine calls that can be used in PCRE/Onigmo, but you may define the subpattern as a variable and build the pattern dynamically:

```js
var target = "16-10-2017";
var  p1 = "[0123][0-9]";
var rx = new RegExp("(" + p1 + ")-(" + p1 + ")-(\\d{4})", "g");
console.log(target.replace(rx, "$1/$2/$3"));
```

Comment: I appreciate for all comments. @WiktorStribiżew your comments were exactly what i needed. The theory was the goal . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have to change your regex to this `(([0123][0-9])-){2}(\d{4})`, which mean that it should match two part of `numbers` of two parts `[0123]` and `[a-9]` followed by `-` `(([0123][0-9])-){2}`

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GZxpAx/2)

Comment: There are 2 bottlenecks with this approach: 1) if OP needs to capture both the groups (and it seems OP needs that since both are captured) and 2) in other cases, when the patterns cannot be repeated this way (i.e. when they are adjoining). If the purpose is to extract/remove substrings then it is a perfect work-around for the current scenario.

Comment: thank you @WiktorStribiżew for your information i appreciate it

Comment: @YCF_L. Thank you for sharing your knowlegde.